# How to use the if statement in jinja2 template

Tags: html, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to check if a condition in the linked database is true and then execute some code but I am getting error such as

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

```
{% for prod in prod %}  

  {% if {{prod.sh}} is 1 %}
    
      <pre>Lines to come if true</pre>
  
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The extensive Jinja2 documentation can be found at https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/

About your code - I spot two problems.

1. You should not use `for prod in prod` - rather, but something like `for product in products`, ie name them differently.
2. You do not have to put angle brackets around `prod.sh`. You would do this only when the variable is referenced directly within the HTML code.

So a working code could look like:

```
{% for prod in prod %}  
  {% if prod.sh == 1 %}
      <pre>Lines to come if true</pre>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```